# Create side-by-side environments in Latex

Tags: spacing, environments

I am trying to create three environments that are beside one another and do not fill the entire page as seen in the attached image. Within each environment, I am trying to add the cvref function, attached is the necessary cls code.

test.cls

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\@ifl@t@r\fmtversion{2018/04/01}{\UseRawInputEncoding}{}
\ProvidesClass{altacv}[2018/07/27 AltaCV v1.1.4, yet another alternative class for a résumé/curriculum vitae.]
\newif\if@academicons
\DeclareOption{academicons}{\@academiconstrue}
%% v1.1.3: Choice of round/square photo
\newif\if@normalphoto
\DeclareOption{normalphoto}{\@normalphototrue}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{extarticle}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass{extarticle}

\RequirePackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{fontawesome}

%% v1.1: Optionally load academicons
\if@academicons
  %% Patch to make academicons compilable with XeLaTeX
  \ExplSyntaxOn
  \msg_redirect_name:nnn { fontspec } { font-not-found } { none }
  \ExplSyntaxOff
  \RequirePackage{academicons}
  \newfontfamily{\AI}{academicons.ttf}
\fi

\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{accent}{blue!70!black}
\colorlet{heading}{black}
\colorlet{emphasis}{black}
\colorlet{body}{black!80!white}
\newcommand{\itemmarker}{{\small\textbullet}}
\newcommand{\ratingmarker}{\faCircle}

\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\RequirePackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\setlist{leftmargin=*,labelsep=0.5em,nosep,itemsep=0.25\baselineskip,after=\vskip0.25\baselineskip}
\setlist[itemize]{label=\itemmarker}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{dashrule}
\RequirePackage{multirow,tabularx}
\RequirePackage{changepage}
% \RequirePackage{marginfix}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcommand{\divider}{\textcolor{body!30}{\hdashrule{\linewidth}{0.6pt}{0.5ex}}\medskip}

\newenvironment{fullwidth}{%
  \begin{adjustwidth}{}{\dimexpr-\marginparwidth-\marginparsep\relax}}
  {\end{adjustwidth}}

\newcommand{\emailsymbol}{\faAt}
\newcommand{\phonesymbol}{\faPhone}
\newcommand{\homepagesymbol}{\faChain}
\newcommand{\locationsymbol}{\faMapMarker}
\newcommand{\linkedinsymbol}{\faLinkedin}
\newcommand{\twittersymbol}{\faTwitter}
\newcommand{\githubsymbol}{\faGithub}
\newcommand{\orcidsymbol}{\aiOrcid}
\newcommand{\mailsymbol}{\faEnvelope}

\newcommand{\printinfo}[2]{\mbox{\textcolor{accent}{\normalfont #1}\hspace{0.5em}#2\hspace{2em}}}
\newcommand{\weblinks}[3]{\mbox{\textcolor{accent}{\normalfont #1}\hspace{0.5em}{\href{#2}{#3}}\hspace{2em}}}
\newcommand{\name}[1]{\def\@name{#1}}
\newcommand{\tagline}[1]{\def\@tagline{#1}}
\newcommand{\photo}[2]{\def\@photo{#2}\def\@photodiameter{#1}}
\newcommand{\email}[2]{\weblinks{\emailsymbol}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\mailaddress}[1]{\printinfo{\mailsymbol}{#1}}
\newcommand{\phone}[1]{\printinfo{\phonesymbol}{#1}}
\newcommand{\homepage}[2]{\weblinks{\homepagesymbol}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\twitter}[1]{\printinfo{\twittersymbol}{#1}}
\newcommand{\linkedin}[2]{\weblinks{\linkedinsymbol}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\github}[2]{\weblinks{\githubsymbol}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\orcid}[1]{\printinfo{\orcidsymbol}{#1}}
\newcommand{\location}[1]{\printinfo{\locationsymbol}{#1}}
   
\newcommand{\cvsection}[2][]{%
  \bigskip%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{}{}{\marginpar{\vspace*{\dimexpr1pt-\baselineskip}\raggedright\input{#1}}}%
  {\color{heading}\LARGE\bfseries\MakeUppercase{#2}}\\[-1ex]%
  {\color{heading}\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}\par}\medskip
}

\newcommand{\cvref}[4]{%
  \smallskip
  \textcolor{emphasis}{\textbf{#1}}\par
  \smallskip\normalsize
  \ifstrequal{#2}{}{}{
  \textbf{\color{accent}#2}\par
  \smallskip}
  \begin{description}[font=\color{accent},style=multiline,leftmargin=1.25em]
  \item[\small\normalfont\mailsymbol] #3
  \item[\small\normalfont\phonesymbol] #4
  \end{description}
  \medskip
%   \medskip
}


\newenvironment{cvcolumn}[1]{\begin{minipage}[t]{#1}\raggedright}{\end{minipage}}

\RequirePackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
%% For removing numbering entirely when using a numeric style
% \setlength{\bibhang}{1em}
% \DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\makebox[\bibhang][l]{\itemmarker}}
% \setlength{\biblabelsep}{0pt}
\defbibheading{pubtype}{\cvsubsection{#1}}
\renewcommand{\bibsetup}{\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\makebox[\bibhang][l]{\itemmarker}}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.25\baselineskip}

% v1.1.2: make it easier to add a sidebar aligned with top of next page
\RequirePackage{afterpage}
\newcommand{\addsidebar}[2][]{\marginpar{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{}{}{\vspace*{#1}}%
  \input{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\addnextpagesidebar}[2][]{\afterpage{\addsidebar[#1]{#2}}}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \color{body}
  \raggedright
}
```

It is called in the following snippet:

test.tex

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{altacv}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=9cm,marginparwidth=6.8cm,marginparsep=1.2cm,top=1.25cm,bottom=1.25cm,footskip=2\baselineskip}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[default]{lato}
\definecolor{Mulberry}{HTML}{72243D}
\definecolor{SlateGrey}{HTML}{2E2E2E}
\definecolor{LightGrey}{HTML}{666666}
\colorlet{heading}{Sepia}
\colorlet{accent}{Mulberry}
\colorlet{emphasis}{SlateGrey}
\colorlet{body}{LightGrey}
\renewcommand{\itemmarker}{{\small\textbullet}}
\renewcommand{\ratingmarker}{\faCircle}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{fullwidth}
    \cvsection{References}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{flushleft}
            \cvref{test}{test}{\href {mailto:test}{test}}{test}
        \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{center}
            \cvref{test}{test}{\href {mailto:test}{test}}{test}
        \end{center}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{flushright}
            \cvref{test}{test}{\href {mailto:test}{test}}{test}
        \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}
\end{fullwidth}
  \medskip
\end{document}
```

[image]

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. I tried a tabular environment, but it won't let me use the cvref function within the cells.

Using minipages, I get the following result:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet be compilable? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: @Mensch I fixed the snippet, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You weren't entirely clear about what the problem was, but I'm assuming you want the email address and phone number to use the same kind of aligning as the lines above them, so the first set is flushleft, the second centered, and the third flushright? (I'm not crazy about that arrangement, but I'm assuming it's what you want?)

If so, you shouldn't define `\cvref` to put those in a description environment.

Just as a first stab, you might want to redefine `\cvref` as follows:

```
\newcommand{\cvref}[4]{%
  \smallskip
  \textcolor{emphasis}{\textbf{#1}}\par
  \smallskip\normalsize
  \ifstrequal{#2}{}{}{
  \textbf{\color{accent}#2}\par
  \smallskip}
  {\color{accent}%
      {\small\normalfont\mailsymbol} #3\par
      {\small\normalfont\phonesymbol} #4\par%
  }%
  \medskip%
}
```

I'd also use `0.33\linewidth` rather than `0.5\textwidth` for the minipages, so that they take up the entire width, but I suppose that depends a bit on how the rest of the CV is going to look and what you want lined up.

[image: cv example]

But if want to keep it as `0.5\textwidth` you get:

[image: cv example with smaller boxes]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thank you. You mentioned you were not crazy about this arrangement, how would you go about improving it?

Comment: I'd probably just have them all left-aligned, or maybe all center-aligned. All the same anyway. I'd want real examples and test both to see which I liked better.